# Do I correctly understand working of asynchronous blocking I/O select() function?

Tags: sockets, select, asynchronous, io, blocking

For example here (http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs168/f12/handouts/async.pdf) is said that:

> select() works by blocking until something happens on a ﬁle descriptor (which can represent an actual
>   ﬁle, a pipe, or a network socket). What’s ‘something’? Data coming in, being able to write to the ﬁle
>   descriptor, or a timeout — you tell select() what you want to be woken up by.
>   Most select()-based servers are structured around a event loop consisting of the following:
>    1) Fill up a fd set structure with the ﬁle descriptors you want to know when data comes in on.
>    2) Fill up a fd set structure with the ﬁle descriptors you want to know when you can write on.
>    3) Call select() and block until something happens.
>    4)Once select() returns, check to see if any of your ﬁle descriptors was the reason you woke up. If so,
>   ‘service’ that ﬁle descriptor in whatever particular way your server needs to.
>    Repeat this process forever.

Do I correctly understand that, for example, I have list of four sockets, from which I would like to read. I pass a select()  this list, and then call this function. It waits some time and then return me that sockets which have pieces of data ready to read. I read this data and then again call select() and so on. I am just trying  to imagine principle how it looks if, for example, four clients send simultaneously any image to such server. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. A webserver utilizes sockets with (usually) TCP protocol. What do you mean by how does it work exactly?

Comment: Simultaneously is a strong word. The odds are they won't arrive at the same time at the server, but even if they do, that means all of your file descriptors will be available for read. So you can read from all of them and call select(). What problems do you see?

Comment: Thank you for help! I almost begin understand. But if I have three file descriptors all of them are ready for I/O. Does Select() returns me notice that all this descriptors are ready and I can process them or it returns me first ready descriptor?

Comment: As stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> But if I have three file descriptors all of them are ready for I/O.
>   Does Select() returns me notice that all this descriptors are ready
>   and I can process them or it returns me first ready descriptor?

`man select`

> On exit, the sets are modified in place to indicate which file
>   descriptors actually changed status.

Note the plural: *descriptors*. (Actually, this is not quite right, since the file descriptors need not *change* status - they may be ready already when `select()` is called.) So, `select()` returns all the descriptors which are ready.